FFMPEG: A small timestamp difference results in two-frame difference in the output of trim
As the background for the question, I use a programmatically generated complex filter to compose a video out of many inputs. Small errors accumulate and so I need precise trims (re-encoding is fine).
For example, I need 44 frames from the linked video (FPS=30) beginning at a given frame.
Here are two attempts (with ffmpeg version 6.1.1):
Attempt 1:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "trim=start=3.2666666666666666:end=4.7333,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -an output.mp4

Attempt 2:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "trim=start=3.2666666666666666:end=4.7334,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -an output.mp4

While the difference in the end timestamp is only 0.0001, the first attempts results in 43 frames (duration of 1.433333 seconds), while the second one gives 45 frames (duration of 1.50 seconds). No matter what I put in the end timestamp, I cannot get 44 frames...
I get the number of frames by:
ffprobe -show_frames output.mp4 | grep FRAME | wc -l

(dividing this number by two, since it counts both [FRAME] and [/FRAME])
What is the explanation for this behavior and how can I predictably trim the frames I need?
UPDATE The same behavior is observed if I use start_frame and end_frame. For the range from 98 to 141, I get 43 frames. For the range from 98 to 142, I get 45 frames. I cannot get 44...

Your 2nd command outputs 44 frames with ffmpeg 7.1 (45 frames with ffmpeg 4.4.5) from that input.mp4 (checked via Invisor).
Also this outputs 44 frames with ffmpeg 7 (45 frames with ffmpeg 4):
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "trim=start_frame=98:end_frame=142,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -an output.mp4


Adding -fps_mode passthrough seems to solve the issue.
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -fps_mode passthrough -vf "trim=start=3.2666666666666666:end=4.7334,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -an output.mp4
After adding -fps_mode passthrough there are 44 output frames.

It looks like a bug in the trim filter (or in FFmpeg filters mechanism).
I don't know why adding -fps_mode passthrough helps, but I guess the bug is somehow related to the timestamps of the frames passed to the trim filter.

Note: The solution seems to work with FFmpeg version 6.1.1, but it's not working with FFmpeg version 7.1
